# Meteor MongoDB : Aggregate query date for particular month and date

Tags: mongodb, date, meteor, aggregate

Im trying to convert my application from python to Meteor.

I want to use below aggregate query to in meteor which works in python:

```
collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          { $eq: [{ $year: "$updated_time" }, 2018] },
          { $eq: [{ $month: "$updated_time" }, 12] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

collection already has data with:

```
 "update_time" ( "updated_time" : ISODate("2018-12-27T15:35:00.857Z"),)
```

field with ISO format.

When I tried the below in Meteor I get `$updated_time` error:

> ReferenceError: $updated_time is not defined.

```
const data = collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          { $eq: [{ $year: $updated_time }, "2018"] },
          { $eq: [{ $month: $updated_time }, "12"] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

I expect all records in collection with updated_time 2018_12.

Comment: In the second query the updated_time should be in quotes like `{ $year: "$updated_time" }`

Comment: Thank you.. that was  a silly one . it really different how it works in python and in meteor